# Keeping TOC layers unchecked on first load in ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: dojo, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am using NLiu's TOC widget for displaying the layers. It is working perfectly, however, I wanted to keep all layers unchecked when it is loading on the browser (for performance reason). I tried to find a way on its javascript files but not succeed.

Any clue to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Set the layer's visible layers to none:

```
layer.setVisibleLayers([])
```